# ISO How to program ActiveX button in Workbook 1, to run macros in Workbook 2?

Tags: excel, activex, vba

Situation:

I have two workbooks:

- Workbook #1: A Downloaded data set from online data repository
- Workbook #2: A Master collection of Macros

I have built a collection of Macros to format a data set after it's been downloaded from an online repository. This data set can differ greatly based on features that users have chosen before downloading the data. The macros I created cover all possible scenarios. Thus, when opening the View Macros dialog box there are an overwhelming amount to choose from. Even with efficient naming conventions it's too much to sift through for my audience, who has an average to low experience level with Excel.

In order to simplify their experience, I wanted to level the playing field by simply providing a "Go" button after they choose from an ActiveX dropdown list.

I successfully created the dropdown, populated the list, and upon activation of the "Go" button, the selection triggers a specific Macro to run.

**MY PROBLEM:**

I need the Subcode on the "Go" button in Workbook #2 to force the macros to run in Workbook #1.

Thank you ahead of time for all your help!

Comment: Post a sample macro. You can activate another workbook before running code. You can reference elements in workbooks other than the workbook that has the code.

Comment: Teylyn, I know it's possible. I had no doubt of that. What I need is actual code to play with or alternative methods that would be more efficient. I am sure there are methods I haven't considered.

Comment: TO CLARIFY: Most tutorials I have found online are explaining how to run macros saved on an inactive workbook on the current workbook. THATS NOT WHAT I NEED. I need to know how to activate a macro from workbook #1(the active workbook), but it does the work in workbook #2(the inactive workbook). Like a light switch in house wired to a secondary house.

Answer (score 0):

You can take cues from the macro recorder.

Here is some basic code that is stored in one workbook and manipulates cells in another workbook.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim mlib As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim ms As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set mlib = ActiveWorkbook ' the file with the macros
Set ms = mlib.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' write into the macro workbook
ms.Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "asdf"

'activate another workbook that is already open and is called somefile.xlsx
Windows("somefile.xlsx").Activate

' set variables to reference that workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' write something into somefile.xlsx
ws.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "copy me"

'copy something within somefile.xlsx
ws.Range("B1").Copy ws.Range("B2")

' copy something from the macro workbook to the somefile workbook
ms.Range("A1").Copy ws.Range("A5")

' activate the macro workbook

mlib.Activate


End Sub
```

I asked for some sample code so I could explain in ***your*** context.

There are about a dozen different ways how you can identify the "other" file instead of hard-coding it into the macro. If you could be bothered to provide a bit more information, that little detail could also be taken care of.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a try. I built a phase one that works...but I will try this as a phase 2, and see if it gives me better control.